# Identify if a 2D list contains a list in Dart/Flutter

Tags: android, list, dart, flutter

How do I identify if a 2D list contains another list without using nested for-loops?

I am looking for a method similar to `in` in python. I tried using `list.contains(x)`, but it doesn't seem to identify lists:

```
List a = [[1,2],[1,1],[2,2]];
List b = [1,2];
int c = 1;

b.contains(c)    // returns true
a.contains(b)    // returns false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, dart compares high-level objects with references, but you need value based comparison because collection are high-level objects. `collection` package has equality methods for that case. Example:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() async {
  final element = [1, 2];
  final b = [
    [1, 2] // equal values with element but not referenced
  ];
  final c = [element];

  print(b.contains(element)); // prints false
  print(c.contains(element)); // prints true

  for (final e in b) {
    print(ListEquality().equals(e, element)); // prints true
  }
}
```

Edit: The solution up above, now, is useful for `Dart-only` applications. If you are developing a `Flutter` application, it got couple of new methods:

`listEquals` for Lists: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/listEquals.html

`mapEquals` for Maps: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/mapEquals.html

`setEquals` for Sets: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/setEquals.html

So, in our example, solution is:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

print(b.any((e) => listEquals(e, element))); // prints true
```