# How can I reach unique pairs in nested list in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have code example like this :

[image]

Here I want to access only unique pairs within the intArr list.
I wanted to output like this ; [0, 0] [1, 1]  [1, 2] [1, 3]
For now, it doesn't matter if the pairs are in order from smallest to largest

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would store the lists that you have already printed in a variable `List<List<int>> alreadySeen` and check before printing if that variable contains the list to be printed.

```dart
void main() {
  List<List<int>> intArr = [
     [0, 0],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 2],
     [1, 3],
     [1, 2],
  ];
 
  List<List<int>> alreadySeen = [];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
    if(!contains(alreadySeen, intArr[i])) {
      print(intArr[i]);
      alreadySeen.add(intArr[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

The function `contains` would have 2 nested for loops, one to loop through the main list and the other to loop through the list we are searching for.
If the `needle` values match a list in the main list, the variable `found` stays `true` and the function returns `true`

```dart
bool contains(List<List<int>> list, List<int> needle) {
  if (list.length == 0 || needle.length == 0) return false;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].length != needle.length) continue;
    
    bool found = true;
    
    for(int j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
      if (list[i][j] != needle[j]) found = false;
    } 
    
    if (found) return true;
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

Note that if you are using flutter there is a function named listEquals that would make the function `contains` easier see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56152130/17560229) however you can't use the basefunction `intArr.contains` since it will compare the `reference` of the arrays and not their `values`

Working [Jdoodle](http://jdoodle.com/ia/kTc).

As @jamesdlin pointed out, if performance is important to you, you would use  a LinkedHashSet instead of List<List> for `alreadySeen` to make the `contains` function O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: thanks! @whygee it works properly.

Comment: please consider marking the answer as accepted (the check mark under) if it fully answers your question.

Comment: thanks for reminding.

Comment: This has an inefficient runtime performance of O(n^2) WRT the length of the outer list.  It can be made O(n) if `alreadySeen` were changed to a `LinkedHashSet` instead.